# Using slicing of a tensor with other tensors to assign value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `nextq` which is a probability distribution over some question set. I have potential answer to each question in `synthetic_answers` which is either 0 or 1. I want to update a tensor called `cur_qinput` by

1. Finding the index with the largest value in `nextq` for each vector in batch
2. If `synthetic_answers` at that index is 1, then set the 3rd feature of `cur_qinput` at that index to 1, otherwise set the 2nd feature.

Here is some non-functional code, it is non functional at the for-loop as I  don't know the properly slice tensors with other tensors/assign values, I just tried to write it in python syntax for clarity of my intent.

```
#nextq shape =  batch_size x q_size
#nextq_index shape =  batch_size
nextq_index = tf.argmax(nextq,axis=1)


#synthetic_answers shape =  batch_size x q_size
#cur_qinput shape = batch_size x q_size x 3

#"iterate over batch", doesn't actually work and I guess needs to be done entirely differently
for k in tf.range(tf.shape(nextq_index)[0]):
    cur_qinput[k,nextq_index[k],1+synthetic_answers[k,nextq_index[k]]]=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that your data are as follows since there are no examples in the question.

```
import tensorflow as tf

nextq = tf.constant([[1,5,4],[6,8,10]],dtype=tf.float32)
synthetic_answers = tf.constant([[0,1,1],[1,1,0]],dtype=tf.int32)
cur_qinput = tf.random_normal(shape=(tf.shape(nextq)[0],tf.shape(nextq)[1],3))
```

First you can use `tf.one_hot` to build `mask` to describe whether `synthetic_answers` at that index is equal to `1`.

```
nextq_index = tf.argmax(nextq,axis=1)
# [1 2]
nextq_index_hot = tf.one_hot(nextq_index,depth=nextq.shape[1],dtype=tf.int32)
# [[0 1 0]
#  [0 0 1]]
mask = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(nextq_index_hot,synthetic_answers),tf.equal(nextq_index_hot,1))
# [[False  True False]
#  [False False False]]
```

Then you expand `mask` to the same shape as `cur_qinput`.

```
mask = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(mask,dtype=tf.int32)+1,depth=3)
# [[[0. 1. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 1.]
#   [0. 1. 0.]]
#
#  [[0. 1. 0.]
#   [0. 1. 0.]
#   [0. 1. 0.]]]
```

Finally you can `tf.where` to assign `1` to `cur_qinput`.

```
scatter = tf.where(tf.equal(mask,1),tf.ones_like(cur_qinput),cur_qinput)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    cur_qinput_val,scatter_val = sess.run([cur_qinput,scatter])
    print(cur_qinput_val)
    print(scatter_val)
[[[ 1.3651905  -0.96688586  0.74061954]
  [-1.1236337  -0.6730857  -0.8439895 ]
  [-0.52024084  1.1968751   0.79242617]]

 [[ 1.4969068  -0.12403865  0.06582119]
  [ 0.79385823 -0.7952771  -0.8562217 ]
  [-0.05428046  1.4613343   0.2726114 ]]]
[[[ 1.3651905   1.          0.74061954]
  [-1.1236337  -0.6730857   1.        ]
  [-0.52024084  1.          0.79242617]]

 [[ 1.4969068   1.          0.06582119]
  [ 0.79385823  1.         -0.8562217 ]
  [-0.05428046  1.          0.2726114 ]]]
```

Comment: Excellent, I didn't think about tf.one_hot to make the mask from the indices but now it seems obviously the right way.